# Can someone exlpain advantage spring-security PreAuthorize annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

For example:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin') && hasPermission('save', #user)")
void updateUser(User user) {
  // some code
}
```

And some example implementation without PreAuthorize.

```java
void updateUser(User user) {
  Security.hasRole(Roles.ADMIN);
  Security.hasPermission(Permission.SAVE, user);
  // some code
}
```

The second example is more easy to understand. Can be refactored by IDE (rename role, or find all role usages). Code check at compile time. Work more fast. And may other advantages.

Why spring-security developers chose annotations and SpEL? Can some-one explain it?

Only one reason what i can find - more easy access to ApplicationContext. But as far as i can see, spring security any way work through SecurityContextHolder singleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most advantage (from my point of view) is, that it can be easily deactivated (or more correct, not activated) in test.

So I can write my tests (unit test, functional test, ...) without paying any attention to the security stuff. So that the tests can concentrate on the function they want to test.

Of course this is also possible with the "explicit" version (second example), but then I need to take care about it in the test, that would make the tests longer (more code) and also means more stuff to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Ralph answer I would add a couple of other advantages.

1. @PreAuthorize (& co.) are meta-annotated with @Documented, this means that the annotation will be shown in the Javadocs of the secured method. A reader of your documentation will know immediately that the method is secured and under what conditions.
2. Since it is meta-annotated with @Inherited, you can add the @PreAuthorize to a parent Class, and automatically have all the hierarchy to be secured without implementing any additional pattern.